# Mostrar valor de evento da Página 2 em um input da Página 1

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

Tenho duas páginas e quero que o valor de um evento (script abaixo) da Página 2 seja mostrada em um input da Página 1.

HTML da Página 1:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item text-center>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="forca"></ion-input>
      <ion-label stacked>Força</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

HTML da Pagina 2:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding #item>
      <ion-item (click)="showConfirm()">
        <ion-avatar item-left>
          <img src="assets/img/adagas.png">
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>Adagas Sangrentas</h2>
        <h3>Força +1, Agilidade +1</h3>
        <p>Adagas preparadas para derramar sangue, feitas com lâminas forjadas em aço raro e fino.</p>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item-options side="left">
        <button
          [style.backgroundColor]= "ativo ? 'green' : 'red'"
          (click)="usar()"
        >Usar</button>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
```

Script da Página 2:

```
usar() {
    this.ativo = !this.ativo;
    this.forca = 1;
    console.log(this.forca);
    }
```

Nesse caso, clicando em "Usar" o valor do input "força" mudar para 1.

Answer (score 0):

Uma das formas que vc pode fazer isso é usando Events

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/

No construct da sua página 1 vc inicia o ouvinte do evento.

```
events.subscribe('usar:forca', (valor) => {
    this.forca = valor
});
```

Sempre que o evento *'usar:forca'* for chamado essa função será executada passando o valor para sua variável forca.

Na sua função usar() da página 2 basta chamar o evento passando o valor de forca.

```
usar() {
   this.ativo = !this.ativo;
   this.forca = 1;
   console.log(this.forca);
   events.publish('usar:forca', this.forca);
}
```

Não sei como está o restante do seu código. Se a página 2 precisar ser fechada é só fechar depois de acionar o evento.